# Search for file through directories

Tags: java, file, search

I am trying to search for a text file in multiple directories, then add the directory path to an array list.

How can I do this?

Here is what I have so far:

```
File folder = new File("path\\dir");
File folder1 = new File("path\\dir1");
ArrayList<File> flielist = new ArrayList<File>();
flielist.add(folder);
flielist.add(folder1);
for (int i = 0; i < flielist.size(); i++){
  File dir = flielist.get(i);
  System.out.println(dir.getName());
  if(dir.listFiles() != null){
    for (File file : dir.listFiles())
    {
      String filename = file.getName();
      if(filename.equals("rashed")){
        System.out.println("found" + file.getPath());
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Please read, how to create a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
public class FileSearch {

    private List<String> result;

    public List<String> getResult() {
        if (result == null) {
            result = new ArrayList<String>();
        }
        return result;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        FileSearch fileSearch = new FileSearch();
        fileSearch.search(new File("C:/Users"), "rashed.txt");
        int count = fileSearch.getResult().size();
        if (count == 0) {
            System.out.println("\nNo result found!");
        } else {
            System.out.println("\nFound " + count + " result!\n");
            for (String matched : fileSearch.getResult()) {
                System.out.println("Found : " + matched);
            }
        }
    }

    public void search(File file, String filename) {
        if (file.isDirectory()) {
            System.out.println("Searching directory ... " + file.getAbsoluteFile());
            //do you have permission to read this directory?
            if (file.canRead()) {
                if (file.listFiles() != null) {
                    for (File temp : file.listFiles()) {
                        if (temp.isDirectory()) {
                            search(temp, filename);
                        } else {
                            if (filename.equalsIgnoreCase(temp.getName())) {
                                getResult().add(temp.getAbsoluteFile().toString());
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            } else {
                System.out.println(file.getAbsoluteFile() + "Permission Denied");
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks , but still doesnt work , i am getting this error  NullPointerException on line ::  if (filename.equalsIgnoreCase(temp.getName())) ?? any idea ?

Comment: you need to set directory path as yours

Comment: i did for sure , it works only when i delete result.add(temp.getAbsoluteFile().toString());